# Replacing an old table with a new one in the Django database?

Tags: django, database

Hi I am working on a Django Project and added the functionality of importing a csv file to the Django database using the following code

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()


    def import_csv(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            with open('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Projekt/test2.csv') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                for column in reader:
                    p = CSV(gebäude=column[0], etage=column[1], raum=column[2], dose=column[3])
                    p.save()
                return redirect('upload:index')
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(
        request, "upload/csv_upload.html", {"form": form}
    )
```

However if i make changes to the csv file and add it to the database it just adds everything and I have the data basically twice in the table. I would like to know if there is any option to just replace the old data in the table with the changed data, instead of just adding it to the table. I use the standard sqlite3 database.

This is the csv file

```
25.41, 1, 21, 10
25.42, 2, 22, 14
25.43, 1, 23, 13
25.44, 3, 24, 12
25.45, 2, 25, 11
25.46, 0, 15, 23
```

This is my models.py

```
class CSV(models.Model):
    gebäude = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    etage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    raum = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dose = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And my Html form

```
<h2>Upload CSV</h2>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can just do `CSV.objects.all().delete()` to empty the existing table.

Comment: But the csv file originally has a lot of entries (around 10000) so it would be kind of a performance problem I think. I thought about checking for a unique id in the table to avoid doubled data but I do not know how to access the database through the view for that method.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you're already accessing the database via the CSV model, you can just do `CSV.objects.get(id=your_unique_id)`. But what is the unique ID in this case?

Comment: So the problem I have is that, lets say I have 10000 entries in the CSV file and than another 1000 need to be added to the database without having two entries with the same values. And to add the changed file I would like to use the function above (import_csv). So without deleting the existing data (just adding the hypothetically 1000 new entries). CSV.objects.get() just gives me the values at e.g. id = 2 so I think it is not solving the problem.

Comment: That's still not clear. What is "the same values"? Do you mean the unique combination of gebäude, etage, raum, dose? Or is one of them the unique identifier? And `get()` can be used with any field, eg `CSV.objects.get(gebäude="25.41")`.

Comment: Yes the combination sorry if that was not clear. But the problem with `CSV.objects.get()` is that it is basically a query to get data from the database, but as stated earlier I would like to add data to the existing database table with the view function above.